# how to use an equation in truepart of IIf function in access

Tags: ms-access

in `access` I have a calculated field, the equation to be calculated is:

```
[Field1]*Exp((-1.2*([Field2]/[Field3])))
```

Now I want to use an `IIf` function in this field like this:

```
IIf([TDN Equation Class]="Forage","=[Field1]*Exp((-1.2*([Field2]/[Field3])))","0")
```

but the `truepart` expression doesn't work and show me the exact equation:

```
=[Field1]*Exp((-1.2*([Field2]/[Field3])))
```

what should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
=IIf([TDN Equation Class]="Forage",[Field1]*Exp(-1.2*[Field2]/[Field3]),0)
```

Nested example:

```
=IIf([TDN Equation Class]="Forage",[Field1]*Exp(-1.2*[Field2]/[Field3]),IIf([SomeOtherField]=SomeValue,10,0))
```

Comment: tnx, is there any function for if() else if() else if() and go on in access ?

Comment: Not as a one-liner. But you can _nest_ the `IIf` expressions quite deep.

Comment: tnx, would you please explain it to me a little more with an example?

Answer (score 2):

It showed you the equation because you wrapped it in quotes. Also the = operator is not needed, try simply:

```
IIf([TDN Equation Class]="Forage",[Field1]*Exp((-1.2*([Field2]/[Field3]))),"0")
```